# How about if use GUI class in QT CLI application?

Tags: qt, console, qt5, qstandarditemmodel, treemodel

I am developing a Qt CLI application.
I know that we should only use the class of CORE lib

```
QT       -= gui
CONFIG   += console
```

But I want to use `QStandardItemModel` for a tree view (show on console window).
How about if I set **Qt += gui** and include **`QStandardItemModel`** in my code and develop a CLI application.

P/s: Could I create a **standard tree model** for developing both GUI and CLI application instead of **`QStandardItemModel`** (only work on GUI)?

Comment: I think you can sub class the `QAbstractItemModel` and use it without linking to QtGui module, as `QAbstractItemModel` is in QtCore and independent from GUI.

Comment: How about if I set Qt += gui and include QStandardItemModel in my code and develop a CLI application?
What problem or conflict?

Comment: I can set QT += GUI
But I am not sure that what problem or conflict when I set GUI for CLI app.

Comment: You can easily add `QT += gui` without any problems and continue to use a `QCoreApplication`, as long as you do not use any class that might show anything GUI-related. If you ever do accidentily, Qt will print a warning and not just crash, so it's pretty safe to use that way